How to pass value from form1 to user control, the user control is within the form2 (winforms c#)
When I pass the value from Form1 to user control and display the value that I get from Form1, it displays null. My user control is contained within another form, Form2.
Form 1 code:
namespace test
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     String user;
     public Form1()
      {
       InitializeComponent();
      }
     


      private void Login_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       user = username.Text;
       MyuserControl ctrl = new MyuserControl();
       
       ctrl.Data = user; //will send the value of the user to the Data
       Form2 f2 = new Form2();
       f2.Show();
       this.Hide();

      }

  }
}


User Control code:
 namespace test
{
  public partial class MyuserControl : UserControl
  {
    Private String data;
    public String Data { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }

    public MyuserControl()
    {
       initializeComponent();
    }
    
     private void MyuserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     label1.Text = Data;
     }
  }
}


I tried using constructors, getters, and setters. However, when I apply this to Form2 instead of user controls, it successfully passes the value.
I want the value to be passed on my user control.

Do you actually have an instance of your user control being created in the Form2? Based on your Form1, you are creating a new user control each time and setting its data, and the control is not added to a second form in your given code.

The user control has been incorporated into the Form2 designer. I’ve also attempted to create an instance of the user control within the form2 code. There’s a label present in user control, and my intention is for it to reflect the updated value when I pass it and Form2 is displayed.

If the user control is a part of Form2, and there's no direct reference from Form1 to the user control or vice versa (which is a good thing, you generally don't want to add references to controls in other forms, that just complicate things), then the value must be passed via the one thing they both have references to - which is Form2.
Since the user control is added to Form2's controls in the form designer, it's initialized in the InitializeComponent call that happens in the auto-generated constructor of Form2.
This means the simplest way to pass data to that control would be to add a method to Form2 that Form1 can interact with, and have that method pass the data to the user control:
in Form2:
internal void SetUser(string user) => MyuserControl1.Data = user; 

and in Form1:
private void Login_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   user = username.Text;
   Form2 f2 = new Form2();
   f2.SetUser(user);
   f2.Show();
   this.Hide();
}


If your User control is inside Form2 you will need to do something like this:
namespace test
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     String user;
     public Form1()
      {
       InitializeComponent();
      }
        

      private void Login_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       user = username.Text;

       // this user control is just an instance that is not doing anything
       // and it is not part of Form2, the user control you have on form2 is not the same as this variable
       // MyuserControl ctrl = new MyuserControl();           
       // ctrl.Data = user; //will send the value of the user to the Data

       Form2 f2 = new Form2();
       // Instead you will need to pass the value to the user control inside f2 instance
       f2.userControl.Data = user; //this example userControl will be the name of the actual control on your form2
       f2.Show();
       this.Hide();

      }

  }
}

This code might not actually work because controls need to be initialized first on the creation of the new form.  Instead, you should pass the user variable on the constructor of From2 and then after the initialization of the controls change the .Data property of the userControl to the user variable you       passed on the constructor.
namespace test
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     String user;
     public Form1()
      {
       InitializeComponent();
      }


      private void Login_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       user = username.Text;

       Form2 f2 = new Form2(user);
       f2.Show();
       this.Hide();

      }

  }
}

and in the Form2
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
     public Form2(string user)
      {
       InitializeComponent();

       //after the initialization
       this.ctrl.Data = user;
      }

Assuming this.ctrl is the actual User Control name you added to the Form2

By default, the auto-generated constructor of forms is running on the same thread it was called, and so is the InitializeComponent() method, so once the control returns to the code that called the constructor, components are already initialized. Also, controls added in the designer are private by default, so f2.userControl.Data = user; will not compile. Moreover, you don't want to tie Form1 to the implementation detail that is the user control of Form2.

Thanks for the replies. I already solved my problem, it has something to do with instantiating the usercontrol to my form2. Before, I used to drag and drop the user control on my form2. Now, I instantiate the user control directly to my code.

The problem is, that a UserControl is not meant to be shown by itself, it must be put on a Form.
Apparently, Form1 has a TextBox called userName and a Login button.
If the operator clicks on the Login Button, you want to show a new Form (let's say Form2), while hiding Form1. Using visual studio designer you have put the UserControl on Form2. Just before showing Form2, you want the value of Form1.userName.Text in the UserControl.
Before showing your Form2, you have to be aware between the differences between modal and a modeless dialog boxes

The easiest one, the most often used one: Modal Dialog Box. A new Form (dialog box) is shown. Usually the original form is shown below the Modal Dialog box. The operator can't switch to the original form. He has to complete the dialog box before he can continue working in the original form. A model dialog box is shown using Form.ShowDialog. Example: the File Save Dialog Box
Modeless Dialog Box: The operator is free to switch between the original form and the modeless dialog box. Quite often the modeless dialog box shows extra information about the original form. For instance in a drawing program, the coordinates of the selected shape.

It seems to me that you don't want that the operator can do anything in the original form while the form with the user control is being shown. It is windows standard behaviour that the original form is still visible while the modal dialog box is being shown. If you really want to deviate from this windows standard, you can hide the original form. Be aware though, that it will be difficult for the operator to see to which form the dialog box belongs, especially if you have more instances of your program running.
Modal
The UserControl has a string Property UserName and a Label (labelUserName) that should show the value of this string property. In your original design they had the not very descriptive names Data and Label1
How about this:
class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyuserControl()
    {
       initializeComponent();  // this constructs labelLoginName
    }

    public String UserName // This used to be your property Data
    {
        get => this.labelUserName.Text;
        set => this.labelUserName.Text = value;
    }

    ... // other properties, for example, the operator must provide a password
    public string Password => this.textBoxPassword.Text;
}

As you require that labelUserName always shows the value of property UserName, it is better not to create a separate field for this. A separate field makes that you have to synchronize between the field and the displayed value. The Label is constructed when the UserControl is constructed, so it is available immediately after construction of the UserControl, although it is not visible yet.
To make the example more meaningful, I added an output field. The operator sees the displayed login Name and must provide some output: the Password. This is get only.
Using visual studio designer you put MyUserControl on a newly created Form2 on which you put MyUserControl as a field named myUserControl1.
class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      // This constructs myUserControl1
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get => this.myUserControl1.UserName;
        set => this.myUserControl1.UserName = value;
    }

    public string Password => this.MyUserControl1.Password;
}

Of course the operator must say that he has finished using the dialog box, so you added an Ok button, and probably also a cancel button.
Let's continue with Form1.
Form1 has a textBox named textBoxLoginName and a button buttonLogin. When the operator clicks on the login button, you want to show Form2 as a modal Dialog Box. Form2 should show the loginName from the text box in the user control.
Furthermore, you want to deviate from windows standard, and hide Form1, until the operator closes Form2. After that Form1 should interpret the results and act accordingly.
string UserName
{
    get => this.textBoxLoginName.Text;
    set => this.textBoxLoginName.Text = value;
}

void OnButtonLogin_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.PerformLogin();
}

I decided to create a separate method that does the login, so if later you decide that other events should perform a login, like a menu item, or selecting a username from a ComboBox, you can reuse the code.
void PerformLogin()
{
    // create form2, and put the user name in it:
    using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.UserName = this.UserName;

        // just before showing Form2, hide this form; strongly disadvice
        this.Hide();

        // now show Form2 as a modal dialog box, and wait until operator finished
        DialogResult dlgResult = form2.ShowDialog(this);

        // now show Form1 again:
        this.Show();

        // process the result; Although form2 is not visible anymore it still works
        // check whether the operator pressed Ok, or Cancel and act accordingly
        switch (dlgResult)
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                bool passwordOk = this.CheckPassword(form2.UserName, form2.Password);
                if (passwordOk)
                {
                    ... 
                }
                else ...   // what to do if password incorrect?
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                ... // TODO: what to do if no password provided?
                break;
            default:
                ... etc
         }
    } // Form2 and MyUserControl Disposed, not functioning anymore
}

You see that a Modal Dialog Box is very easy to use: your form continues where it left of, after the Modal Dialog Box is closed. You can still ask information from the dialog box, as long as it is not disposed.
Modeless dialog box
Modeless: the operator can switch between Parent form and Child form. Usually they are both visible.
If Form1 is hidden, it is not very useful to show form2 as a modeless dialog box, as the operator can't switch to form1. Just for completeness I'll show how a Modeless dialog box is shown, while both are visible.
The parent form needs to keep a reference to the child form, to keep the form alive:
in Form1 add a property:
Form2 Form2 {get; set;}

If Form1 is about to be closed, while Form2 is still being shown, you have to decide what you want: just Close form2 also, possibly losing entered information, or don't allow closing form1, or warn the operator
React on form OnClosing:
void OnForm1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Form2 != null)
    {
        // what to do? Ask operator if closing is ok?
        // close anyway, possibly loosing information
        // ask Form2 if closing is ok?
        // anyway, fill in:
        e.Cancel = ...         // true means stop the closing
    }
    // else: no form2, continue closing
}

To create Form2:
void CreateForm2()
{
     if (this.Form2 != null) ... // what to do if there is already a Form2?

    this.Form2 = new Form2();
    this.Form2.UserName = this.UserName;
    ....

You also need to subscribe on closing Form2, so if Form2 closes, you can get some information from form2 and Dispose the form.
    this.Form2.Closed += this.Form2Closed;

    // show Form2 as a modeless dialog box
    this.Form2.Show();
}

The event handler if Form2 Closed:
void Form2Closed(object sender, ...)
{
    // Form2 has just been closed, last chance to get information from it
    string passWord = this.Form2.Password;
    ... // process the information from Form2.

    // Dispose and null Form2:
    this.Form2.Dispose();
    this.Form2 = null;
}

You do see that a modeless dialog box is way more work than a modeless dialog box. There is seldom need for a modeless Dialog box. Usually the information that is visible in a modeless dialog child box can also be shown in the parent box itself.
